# taking two times the derivative is squaring

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I don't understand why the following is true : 
We have using the chain rule :

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}$$

But then why :

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} = (\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x})^2$$ ?

Normally it should be :

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}$$

?

I really don't understand what is going on...

Thank you !

Comment: Are you sure these two aren't equal?

Comment: So now if you plug in the first line for $\frac\partial{\partial x}$ in the last ...

Comment: @Yanko I must say that I really don't know... In the second one I am really just applying the operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ on the two elements inside the parenthesis, just because In one dimension $(u+v)' = u' + v'$ but then I don't  know what to do with this expression and get the square...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Got it ! Thank you. This is really strange because in one dimension taking the second derivative is not squaring. But ok ty I got it.